# Linux driver try & catch

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I wrote a Linux driver, and want to read a chunk of memory.  I want to wrap it with try & catch - in case the memory I'm trying to access is unavailable.

How can I do that in C?

i.e.

```
for(i=0;i<base_address.len/sizeof(unsigned); ++i)
{
    seq_printf(seq, "0x%x ",((const volatile unsigned*)base_address.iobase[i]);
}
```

I want to protect access to this - **base_address.iobase[i]**, because of I'm not sure all bits in the scope are accessible.

Comment: Please include some code illustrating your issue, it is quite hard to guess from your description alone.

Comment: Try & catch is C++ and I believe all of Linux is pure (non-standard) C? So what are you actually doing?

Comment: You can use try/catch like mechanism inside Linux kernel :) See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact there is a try-catch like facility in Linux kernel. It's called `exception table` and can be found in `kernel/extable.c` inside Linux source code. Basically you use one of the `_ASM_EXTABLE*` macros defined in `arch/x86/include/asm/asm.h` (assuming you are on x86 platform).

The way it works is you supply the faulty instruction - i.e. the `try` part - and `fixup` address - the `catch` part. This is described more detail in [try/catch in Linux Kernel](https://binarydebt.wordpress.com/2018/11/16/try-catch-in-linux-kernel/).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - **you don't**.

C doesn't provide a try/catch mechanism like C++ does.  Instead you need to check results of each call you make, and perform your own cleanup when you return early, in the standard C idiom.

Look at other drivers for patterns to follow; don't try to invent some mechanism that's different from the rest of the kernel (that way only leads to confusion and pain!).